# Proving a result in Baire categories

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, baire-category

If $A\subset X$ is a $G_\delta$ set and dense in $X$, then what I want to show is that  $X\setminus A$ is of the first Baire category.

Where the meaning of first category is that I can write

$$X\setminus A= \bigcup_n^{\infty}E_n$$

and the sets $E_n \subset X$ are nowhere dense ($X\setminus \overline{E_{n}}$ is dense or $\forall \epsilon>0  $ and $x \in X$ $B_{\epsilon }(x) \nsubseteq \overline{A}$)

> **My attempt**

Then we can write

$$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n} $$

where $C_{n}$ is open for all $n$, this is because $A$ is $G_{\delta}$ so what  I was triying to show that each of the $C_n$ should be dense and then conclude that since I can write the complement using DeMorgan's laws as

$$X\setminus A= \bigcup X\setminus C_n$$

I can get that the complements $X\setminus (X\setminus C_n)$ are dense but  So I think it won't help because this is in fact $C_n$.

So can someone help me to fix this idea (If I am in the right track of course) or provide a different proof of this please?

> **Edition**

I want to conclude that I can

$$X\setminus A= \bigcup_n^{\infty}E_n$$

where the sets $E_n \subset X$ are nowhere dense.
To do that we use the fact that since $A$ is $G_{\delta}$

$$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n} $$

and given that $A$ is dense we have that eah $C_n$ is dense too. So now we may write (By DeMorgan's laws)

$$X\setminus A= \bigcup_n^{\infty} X \setminus C_n$$

So we only need to prove that $X \setminus (X \setminus C_n)$ is dense, but $X \setminus (X \setminus C_n)=C_n$ that is dense, therefore $X \setminus A$ is of first category.

Am I right?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A^c=X\setminus A$ be complement of $A$, $\overline{A}$ be closure of $A$ and $A^o$ be interior of $A$.

We define:

1). $A$ is dense iff $\overline{A}=X$.

2). $A$ is nowhere dense iff $\overline{A}^o=\varnothing$.

In this problem, we will prove that $C_n^c$ is nowhere dense.

First since $A\subset C_n$ and $\overline{A}=X$, there is 
$$
\overline{C_n}\supset \overline{A}=X\quad\text{Thus}\quad \overline{C_n}=X
$$
So $C_n$ is dense. Clearly $\overline{C_n}^c=\varnothing$. Moreover
$$
\overline{C_n}^c=(((C_n^{c})^o)^c)^c=(C_n^{c})^o=\varnothing
$$
Since $C_n$ is open,  $C_n^c$ is closed. So $\overline{C_n^c}=C_n^c$. Thus we have
$$
\overline{C_n^c}^o=(C_n^c)^o=\varnothing
$$
i.e. $C_n^c$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, and I am sorry for the delay :), but how do you see my above answer(well my idea fixed with Nate's answer)? Is it right?

Comment: Why is it not complete ? is because I have read your proof and I think is awesome but those things you used I think are a little bit fancy :)

Comment: No I mean Nate's answer because I think with that it is done right? or what else do I need to prove, because I haven't  seen that two definitions you gave :)

Comment: Nate's answer didn't show that the complement of a dense open set is a (closed) nowhere dense set, which I proved. I use the definition of dense and no nowhere dense set that may not commonly used, but is a standard. A is dense iff closure of A is X. A is nowhere dense iff closure of A has no interior. I think you are on the same direction for you use $X∖(X∖Cn)$.

Comment: Ok let me write my whole proof so you can verify it right? Thnks in advance

Comment: What do you think (I have edited my post ) ?

Comment: Right but I only need to check that $X \setminus (X \setminus C_n)=C_n$ is dense an it is right :)?

Comment: Well as I point it out in my post my definition of nowhere dense is that the complement of the closure is dense, but $X \setminus C_n$ is closed already because $G_\delta $ implies $C_n$ open :) right?

Comment: Yes. Your definition  that $X\setminus \overline{E_{n}}$ is dense is consistent with $\overline{X\setminus E_{n}}$ has no interior as latter part of definition suggest.

Comment: Then what do you think about my proof? :)

Comment: Yes, your proof is right.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) and thanks for your really awesome proof too :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is dense and $A \subset C_n$, it follows that $C_n$ is dense.

Now show that the complement of a dense open set is a (closed) nowhere dense set.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NateEldredge the thing is that it is the problem, that, ok, we know $X \setminus C_n$ is closed but according to my nowhere dense definition I need to show that $X \setminus (\overline{X \setminus C_n})$ is dense right, ooo but wait a minute this is $C_n$ that you have show that is dense right?

Comment: @user162343: Right.

Comment: jajaja so it is done isn't?